# How to abuse user login with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model, controller, actionmethod

I want to abuse a user login.

I have two sales agents: 
name: SalesAgent123
name: HansAlbert

the first time I login as SalesAgent123 with a username and password.

Then with SalesAgent123 still logged in. I want to login as HansAlbert but this time without password and username. So I just want to get the username HansAlbert. So there will be displayed: Welcome HansAlbert.

I have a textfield where a user can enter a string and then a submit(httpPost)
commits the string. The actionmeethod looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [SanaValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult BalieNr(IEntityListLoadOptions entyOptions, ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel model, string accountSalesAgentID)
        {
            SalesAgentLoginInfoModel salesAgentmodel = new SalesAgentLoginInfoModel();
            var salesAgents = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccounts(entyOptions);

            var modelagent = ObjectManager.GetInstance<ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel>();
            Entity SalesAgenWithBaliecodeNr = new Entity();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in salesAgents)
                {
                    ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
                    if (item.ShopAccountType == ShopAccountType.SalesAgent)
                    {
                        if (model.Name == "SalesAgent123")
                        {                           
                            var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(Guid.Parse("8D1E247E-A47B-4683-A14F-37201537C27C"), true);
                            var shopAccount = DataManager.Get<IShopAccount>(Guid.Parse("8D1E247E-A47B-4683-A14F-37201537C27C"));
                            if (shopAccount == null)
                                return HttpNotFound();

                            if (salesAgent99 != null)
                            {

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

So I login with SalesAgent123 then I go to the actionmethod: balieNr and I type: 
SalesAgent123

I get in the method and I see on this line:

```
var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(Guid.Parse("8D1E247E-A47B-4683-A14F-37201537C27C"), true);
```

`var salesAgent` the other user HansAlbert. So that is correct. but if I look then in this method:

```
  protected override SalesAgentLoginInfoModel CreateSalesAgentLoginInfoModel()
        {
            var model = ObjectManager.GetInstance<SalesAgentLoginInfoModel>();
            model.Name = Shop.ShopAccount.Name;
            return model;
        }
```

I still see by `model.Name` SalesAgent123 and also in the backend, I see welcome: SalesAgent123 and not welcome: HansAlbert

the model SalesAgentLoginInfoModel looka like this:

```
public class SalesAgentLoginInfoModel
    {
        public SalesAgentLoginInfoModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the name.
        public virtual System.String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

the ISalesPersonProfile looks like this:

```
 public interface ISalesPersonProfile : IEntity
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Email of this Sales person.
        string Email { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sales person's code.
        string Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Job Title of the Sales person.
        string JobTitle { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the Sales person.
        string Name { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Phone number of the Sales person.
        string Phone { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the related customer id list related with the sales person.
        IList<string> RelatedCustomerIds { get; set; }
    }
```

So my question is: how to abuse username that I can switch from user without filling in username and/or password?

Thank you

If I have to post more information just give me a call. Will be nice.

oke, I changed to this:

IN the  ActionResult BalieNr

I added this:

```
 Session["Name"] = salesAgent.ToString();
```

And in the login view I added this:

```
@model Sana.Commerce.Customization.Account.ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel


<div class="top-dropdown login">
    <div class="opener collapsed">
        <span class="login-title">@Sana.SimpleText("Account")</span>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">
        <div class="welcome border-horizontal">
            @Sana.SimpleText("Login_Welcome")
            <span class="user-name">@Model.Name</span>
            <span>@Session["Name"].ToString()</span>

        </div>
        <a href="@Url.Sana.MyAccount()" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("Login_MyAccount")</a>
        <a href="@Url.Sana.RepresentCustomer()" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_RepresentCustomer")</a>
        <div class="logout border-horizontal">
            <a id="logoutLink" href="@Url.Sana.Logout()" class="arrow-blue">@Sana.SimpleText("Logout_LinkText")</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I run it now. I See this:

Sana.Commerce.Shop.ShopAccount

on this line:

```
 <span>@Session["Name"].ToString()</span>
```

oke, I changed to this:

```
  Session["Name"] = salesAgent.Name;
```

and this:

```
  @Sana.SimpleText("Login_Welcome")
            <span class="user-name">@Session["Name"].ToString()</span>
            <span>@Session["Name"].ToString()</span>
```

I see HansAlbert.

But I it still use: SalesAgent123

Because, if I look in this method:

```
 protected override SalesAgentLoginInfoModel CreateSalesAgentLoginInfoModel()
        {
            var model = ObjectManager.GetInstance<SalesAgentLoginInfoModel>();
            model.Name = Shop.ShopAccount.Name;
            return model;
        }
```

I still see by `mode.Name` the name: SalesAgent123

and this is the method ShopAccounts:

```
 public static ExtendedShopAccountManager ShopAccounts
        {
            get { return (ExtendedShopAccountManager)CommerceFrameworkBase.ShopAccounts; }
        }
```

Comment: I edit the post. Thank you

Comment: So how to overwrite current logged in user? So have somebody any tips? Thank you